# Embedded Glassfish JPA Datasource connection fail

Tags: jpa, junit, glassfish, ejb, derby

I develop some unit tests with trying to connect to the Derby internal database but get the following:

> WARNING:  Local Exception Stack:  Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE'
>   does not exist. Error Code: 20000 Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT
>   = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?    bind => [2 parameters bound] Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET
>   SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:644)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:236)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:216)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:85)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:2831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.QuerySequence.update(QuerySequence.java:340)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.QuerySequence.updateAndSelectSequence(QuerySequence.java:277)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.StandardSequence.getGeneratedVector(StandardSequence.java:71)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.DefaultSequence.getGeneratedVector(DefaultSequence.java:163)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sequencing.Sequence.getGeneratedVector(Sequence.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager$Preallocation_Transaction_NoAccessor_State.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:468)     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:1067)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.ClientSessionSequencing.getNextValue(ClientSessionSequencing.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:349)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:308)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.assignSequenceNumber(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:465)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4231)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:513)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:440)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:269)
>     at com.thevehiclelist.VehicleEJB.createVehicle(VehicleEJB.java:32)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.**intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
>     at $Proxy113.createVehicle(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.thevehiclelist.__EJB31_Generated_*VehicleEJB*_Intf_***Bean*_.createVehicle(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.thevehiclelist.VehicleTest.shouldCreateAVehicle(VehicleTest.java:58)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)  at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)    at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:113)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE'
>   does not exist.   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:562)
>     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:255)
>     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:52)
>     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnection.prepareCachedStatement(ManagedConnection.java:993)
>     at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:173)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1474)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1423)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:697)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:585)
>     ... 86 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE'
>   does not exist.   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 108 more Caused by: ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'SEQUENCE'
>   does not exist.   at
>   org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.UpdateNode.bindStatement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 102 more

My persistence.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="carcmsPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>

        <class>se.while_se.Book</class>
        <class>se.while_se.Car</class>
        <class>com.thevehiclelist.Vehicle</class>



        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:MyTestDb;create=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <!-- <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" /> -->

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And my pom.xml is this:

```
<dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.8.1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
                    <version>10.8.2.2</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
```

It seems like the database not is created in the internal database or am I missing something here?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is commented out. As result it is kind of expected that tables and other database objects (for example sequences) are not created.

```
<!-- <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" /> -->
```

Just remove comments and it should work fine:

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
```

Just as an additional note, having `create=true` in JDBC connection string does not affect this. It is only about creating database itself, not tables and other objects in it.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. But, can you please look at this (which occur when I uncommented that line and was the reason why I did try to uncomment it for the first place): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282889/embedded-glassfish-sql-statement-fail